# Página de Wordpress funciona rara tras actualizar

Tags: wordpress, plugin, seo

Tras instalar manualmente una nueva versión de Wordpress más concretamente la 4.7.5 viniendo de la 4.3.3, algún plugin como el Yaost SEO o el All In One SEO Pack hacen que la página directamente no cargue y se queda en blanco. No entra ni en el menu de administrador y me veo obligado a borrar esos plugins via FTP.

He ido quitando y poniendo a mano el resto de plugins y he llegado a la conclusión de que estos dos plugins (probando ambos por separado) dan problemas.

He seguido el procedimiento de actualización recomendado y esta tarde la página iba bien y esta noche he mirado y ya funcionaba rara.
Una de las páginas donde tenía un formulario hecho con Form Maker directamente no mostraba ni el texto ni el formulario.

¿Tan delicado es esto de actualizar Wordpress? Quería incluir la versión 4.7.5 dado que tenía plugins que no llegaban a la última versión 4.8 pero veo que puede que tenga que volver a la versión anterior.

Datos de versiones:

- PHP 5.3
- MYSQL 5.6
- Wordpress 4.3.11(Vieja) (4.7.5 version nueva que falla)

Después de volver a probar he comprobado que en una página donde tengo un formulario hecho con Form Maker este ni se muestra ni tampoco el texto al entrar como invitado normal a la página pero como administrador si me aparece el contenido de esa página aunque lo tenga en público. Los plugins Yoast SEO o All In One SEO Pack al instalarlos hacen que la página de administrador se vea en blanco y creo que la página en general también, pero restableciendo a la versión anterior de Wordpress parece que todo funciona bien otra vez.
¿Tiene esto algo que ver con la versión de PHP o mysql?
¿Recomendaríais actualizar wordpress?
Ya que mi version vieja (la 4.3.11) Parece un poco desfasada y las nuevas versiones podrían traer cosas interesantes.

Comment: ¿Puedes comentar que versión de PHP y MySQL estas usando? Danos algo más de información, también las versiones de esos plugins. ¿Tienes algún tipo de panel de control (Hosting: Cpanel, Plesk)?

Comment: @Sakrow He actualizado la pregunta con más información pero no se si será suficiente. Esque tampoco puedo dar mas información que esa.

Comment: Con lo que acabas de poner de sobra, si ves que la respuesta te vale, puedes aceptarla como respuesta válida. Si a caso poner las versiones de cada plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El primer y mayor problema que veo es que estas usando `PHP 5.3`, mínimo te recomiendo usar `PHP 5.6`

Después de eso, ¿tienes algún tipo de log del servidor en el que podamos ver si está dando errores al cargar la página?

Estaría bien saber si el tema que tienes instalado es modificado por ti ya que eso también puede influir.

Ten en cuenta que la versión mínima de Wordpress no tiene que ser la misma que la versión mínima de las plugins:

- [Wordpress: PHP 5.2.4](https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/)
- YoastSEO: [Aquí](https://yoast.com/yoast-seo-4-5/) dicen que es necesario actualizar a la versión de PHP 7 pero en [un pull en el repositorio de wordpress-seo](https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/pull/7474/files) de hace 5 días parece que sigue valiendo la 5.2.4.
- All In One SEO Pack: Teóricamente también soporta la 5.2, lo dicen [aquí](https://semperfiwebdesign.com/blog/all-in-one-seo-pack/all-in-one-seo-pack-release-history/) en la versión `2.3.12.4` del 1 de Mayo de 2017.

A si que en teoría no deberías de tener problemas, pero lo que te he comentado, prueba lo primero a cambiar la versión de `PHP` por lo menos a la 5.6 y desde ahí buscamos más cosas.

Comment: Creo que para actualizar PHP tendría que contactar con el proveedor del hosting.
El tema estaba de antes dado que la página no la cree yo, pero si que hice un tema hijo despues de preguntar hace tiempo aquí tambien porque se me pedían modificaciones específicas así que me ví obligado a crear un tema hijo.
Probablemente sea lo que dices de la versión de PHP.

Comment: @Sarkrow Se me olvidaba. Lo que si me da miedo ahora que lo pienso es que al actualizar la versión de PHP haya alguna función o parte del código del theme que se quede obsoleto y provoque que la página casque.

Comment: @Lorthas para eso están las pruebas, si tienes panel tardas segundos en cambiar de una versión a otra. El mayor problema puede ser la parte del tema que tengas desarrollada, ya que la mayoría de plugins de Wordpress soportan la versión `5.6` y si no es así cambia de plugin porque no estará actualizado.

Comment: @Sarkrow Pues va a ser la versión de PHP porque he probado en local donde si tengo la versión 5.6.12 y parece que todo funciona a la perfección.
Gracias